# Have I fried the voltage input on my Arduino Nano?

Tags: pins, voltage

I tried using my Arduino Nano in a circuit, switched on power to the circuit and heard a crack and smelt a bit of burning - something shorted.

I have plugged my Arduino into my PC with a USB, the light comes on - it's detected by my PC, so it's not fried completely.

However, when I try powering the Arduino with a 12V 2A wall adaptor (it was working with that before) no lights. Is it possible I somehow fried the voltage input or ground pins - or the voltage regulator (if it has one)?

Comment: the usb chip is different than the workhorse chip; you can fry one but not the other. usually, the uart survives (if anything does) in my experience.

Comment: Did you try uploading a simple sketch (e.g. blink) to check whether the microcontroller is still working?

Answer (score 0):

12V, 2A through a shorted LDO? Yes. It's toast, or something else in the power path (diode?) is toast.

If you are good at soldering you could maybe replace the component, but probably easier to just use a 5v supply instead.